# How to Color List-items (Strings) in a ListActivity without using XMLs

Tags: android, colors, listactivity, listitem

I have a ListActivity extended class in that i want to display the names of cities and states. Cities should be in blue and states must be in red, i'm using a ListView and an ArrayAdapter to display the list. I've searched a lot but all I've got is using XMLs.
Anyone please help me.. Thanks in advance.

My code looks like this:

```
String cities[]={"....."};
String stated[]={"....."};
private ArrayList<String> list_places = new ArrayList<String>();
Private ArrayAdapter<String> list_adapter;
list_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list_places);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 if(isCity())
   /*Text in blue*/
   list_adapter.add(cities[i]);
 else
   /*Text in red*/
   list_adapter.add(states[i]);
}
setListAdapter(list_adapter);
```

Comment: using XML is the only way through which you can have control over the list items...

Comment: @sandy: well, you can always programmatically create the layout for the list items of course, although I do agree that would be more cumbersome than using predefined xml layouts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this adapter

public class ListColor extends BaseAdapter {

```
String[] items = { "Hello ", "hi", " how are you" };
Context mContext;

public ListColor(Context c) {

    mContext = c;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText(items[arg0]);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    return tv;
}
```

}